# Calculation of triple integral

Tags: calculus

Consider the 3D region R bounded by $x+y+z = 1$, $y =0$, $z=0$. Evaluate $∫∫∫(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ) dx dy dz$ over the region $R$.

I tried to solve this question by taking limits of integration as

$$x: 0 \to 1$$
$$y: 0 \to 1-x$$
$$z: 0 \to 1-x$$

I got the final answer as 29/180. But I am not sure whether this answer is correct or not. Please help me.

Comment: Isn't also $x=0$ in your conditions?

Comment: No, x=0 is not present

Comment: Without the plane $x=0$ the region $R$ is unbounded. In fact, I don't see a way of selecting which of the eight convex sets $R$ is supposed to be in that case? The integral diverges for each and every one of them. Please, check again.

Comment: @Balaji Yes as noted by JL I’ve assumed that x=0 is a constraint otherwise the integral diverges. Check that point again, if you are not dealing with simple improper integrals it is probably a typo in your reference book or notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming also $x=0$ as bound (otherwise the integral diverges), the correct set up should be

$$\int_0^1 dx\int_0^{1-x}dy \int_0^{1-x-y} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \,dz$$

and the final [**result**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%20dz%20dy%20dx,%20x%3D0..1,y%3D0..(1-x),%20z%3D0..(1-x-y)) is equal to 1/20, indeed we have

$$\int_0^{1-x-y} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \,dz=[x^2z+y^2z+z^3/3]_0^{1-x-y}=\\=x^2(1-x-y)+y^2(1-x-y)+\frac13(1-x-y)^3$$

and

$$\int_0^{1-x} x^2(1-x-y)+y^2(1-x-y)+\frac13(1-x-y)^3 dy=\\=[x^2(1-x)-y^2x^2/2+(1-x)y^3/3-y^4/4-(1-x-y)^4/4]_0^{1-x}=\\=x^2(1-x)-\frac12(1-x)^4+\frac13(1-x)^4-\frac14(1-x)^4+\frac14(1-x)^4=x^2(1-x)-\frac16(1-x)^4$$

and

$$\int_0^1 x^2(1-x)-\frac 1 {6}(1-x)^4 dx=\\=[x^3/3-x^4/4+(1-x)^5/30]_0^1=\frac13-\frac14-\frac1{30}=\frac{20-15-2}{60}=\frac{3}{60}=\frac{1}{20}$$

Comment: can you share your complete work as the calculation is very cumbersome. Thanks

Comment: @Balaji I've just added some detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @Balaji Recall also that you can evaluate to accept an answer when a problem is solved here on MSE, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: This is just wrong. The point $(x,y,z)=(-2,1,1)$ satisfies the constraints $x+y+z\le1$, $y\ge0$, $z\ge0$ but is left out from your calculation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I get your point, indeed I’ve assumed also $x=0$ as constraint but I noticed now that it was not included in the OP. If it is not I presume that the integral diverges. I’m going to clarify that point with the OP. Thanks